# Normalizing Flows notations and change of variable formula

Tags: generative-models, normalizing-flow

Maybe it is a silly question, but I am wondering why in some papers the function $f$ is the mapping from $x$ to $z$ and in some others it is the other way around. Typically in this [review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.09257.pdf) we go from $x$ to $z$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) &=p_{\mathbf{Z}}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}))|\operatorname{det} \operatorname{Df}(\mathbf{y})| \\
&=p_{\mathbf{Z}}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}))|\operatorname{det} \operatorname{Dg}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}))|^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
If you look at this course from [Stanford](https://deepgenerativemodels.github.io/notes/flow/), $f$ goes the other way:
$$
p_{X}(x)=p_{Z}\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)\left|\operatorname{det}\left(\frac{\partial f^{-1}(x)}{\partial x}\right)\right|
$$
Maybe it is because the function is bijective?

Comment: as you say it's really just a matter of notation